# header - like files in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, namespace-organisation

Is there a way to 'fake' header files in C# using namespaces? From what I've heard, there is no way to get the preprocessing that they provided in C++; but I'd like the organization aspect of it rather than wrapping classes in namespaces and relying on an IDE to tell me *whats in what*.

for example (note the incorrect syntax)
suppose

```
ns1.cs
iamaclass.cs
iamanotherclass.cs
yaclass.cs
yaaclass.cs
```

where ns1.cs 's contents are:

```
namespace ns1
{
   extern class iamaclass;
   extern class iamanotherclass;

   namespace ns1-nested
   {
      extern class yaclass
      extern class yaaclass
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow, somebody that yearns for header files!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Why do you want to emulate header files? What do they provide that standard C# doesn't?

Comment: Yeah, I also don't see what this is solving, exactly.

Comment: Couldn't generated documentation provide the ability to see what is in an assembly without having to rely on the IDE?

Comment: Also, if you want to see what's in what, use the object browser, or .NET Reflector.  And as it turns out, those tools are far superior to having to grep through header files to find definitions (which might in turn be hidden in macros or nested #includes).

Comment: If by IDE, you mean Microsoft Visual Studio, you are not forced to use it to write .NET apps, and even if you use it, you can layout the files the way you want (except for dependent files, like .designer.cs, etc.)

Comment: har har har guys, to each his/her own :/ . In all practically, this is a matter of preference for a small project where I may at times manually compile rather hitting F7. Having chunks of groupings visible in one file is easier to maintain this way.

Comment: Not a real question, vote to close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the directory structure of your projects match the namespace structure, this goes a long way toward getting the organizational benefits.  Now your project file and associated directory structure contains all of the information proposed in your 'header' file.

Comment: I've been doing just that for my projects. Partially I wanted this mostly out of nogalista, but seeing all of your reactions was.. unexpected? I suppose I was wrong to think out of conventional norm.

Comment: I think the reaction is because header files are really a throw-back to an older generation of compilers, where the correct ordering of dependencies and caching of precompiled headers could save a lot of build time.  Managing the header dependencies was yet another task requiring attention that could otherwise be devoted to more productive development.  As PCs become more powerful, build times are less problematic, so header files, like manual memory management, are perceived as happily discarded artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in C#. The closest you could get is to make your ns1.cs file and fill it with `partial class ....`, but that is really pointless. At that point you should just write a document as you won't really get any compiler help in enforcing the structure.

I would say this is a case of "forget how you did it in C++". Usually it's not important to find out what's inside a namespace, but more important to figure out what namespace a certain class is in, and C#'s organization will show you that perfectly.

Just a small last thing: is there a practical reason you don't want to rely on an IDE, or is it just a nitpick? It's OK to rely on the help of an IDE for much development.